# SQL query to create a single record view of multiple records - Dynamic Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Ok, I think there must be an easier way to do this, I would like to do it dynamically instead of hand writing every line. I am more familiar with MySQL than SQL Server 2008, but I'm not sure how I would do this in MySQL either.

I have 3 tables.

```
Table 1:  USER       id | email | password
Table 2:  METADATA   id | name   (list of fields I need to know about user)
Table 3: USER_META   id | uid | name | value (where I store the user meta data)
```

I do not hard code the METADATA because it changes for each instance of this application. but in this example, lets just say the meta data is "eyes", "phone" , "city" (there are actually many more, there might be 20 this week and 40 next week)

So the way it works is when a user registers, I build the registration form using the METADATA table to build the form. It creates a form with "eyes" , "phone" and "city".

When I save the form, I save a single record into the `USER_META` table for each data item.
So when registering, I get 3 inserts:

```
  insert into USER_META(uid,name,value) values (5,"eyes","brown")
  insert into USER_META(uid,name,value) values (5,"phone","555-1212")
  insert into USER_META(uid,name,value) values (5,"city","San Francisco")
```

Now, I want to write a Stored Procedure that will return a record like this"

```
EXECUTE Get_Meta 5
```

returns:

```
uid |  email  |  eyes | phone | city
5    x@x.com    brown   555-1212  San Francisco;
```

I could write a long hard coded select statement like:

```
DECLARE @UID int;
SELECT  id, email,  
(select value from USER_META
 where uid = @UID and name = 'EYES') as EYES,
(select value from USER_META
 where uid = @UID and name = 'PHONE') as PHONE,
(select value from USER_META
 where uid = @UID and name = 'CITY') as CITY,
FROM  USER 
where id = @UID;
```

But that kind of defeats the whole purpose, and I have to write it again every week whenever the metadata requirements change (eg when we launch another instance).

I would like to have something like this: (forgive me I am not very experienced with Advanced SQL, so maybe this is easy and I just don't know how to do it?) I will write it in basic code terms to try and explain my thinking:

```
DECLARE @UID int;
DECLARE @META_NAMES array;
@META_NAMES = (select NAME from METADATA);

SELECT  id, email,  
 for each (@META_NAMES as $THIS_NAME) {

  (select value from USER_META
   where uid = @UID and name = '$THIS_NAME') as $THIS_NAME,

}
FROM  USER 
where id = @UID;
```

Is there a way to write this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: That's not really a good data model (google EAV).  Out of interest why do you want it in a single row?  Why not just a row for each meta data value?

Comment: @LoztInSpace I think it's more Row Modeling than EAV, - I do have a view that returns all the meta data values in rows. I am creating reports, and while I can group the meta data results and loop through them for my report (the most basic one creates a spreadsheet of users/meta data) - I wanted to build a dynamic query to return that query structure for me instead of having to extract it with code. -

Comment: It might be misleading because I left out some details - the METADATA table also has a "enabled" toggle - so every enabled name/value pair is essential for the instance, there isn't a bunch of empty meta data pairs in USER_META.

Answer (score 1):

You would USE FOR XML_PATH in SQL Server. A workaround for GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT
    U.UID,
    U.EMAIL,
    stuff(
    (
    select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + name + '=' + Value
    from USER_META
    WHERE UID = U.UID
    for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS M
FROM
    USERS U
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d9f2/3)

Comment: Cha, thanks that's a good start, and I could write some code to extract all the name/value pairs from M - that will totally work.   Is there a way to convert the names into field names?

Comment: For this you would use dynamic SQL. You would first extract names using `select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + name from USER_META WHERE UID = 5 for xml path('')` and then use the constructed SQL to pass it to `sp_execute` stored procedure

Comment: Correction: you would use `select cast(',' as varchar(max)) + value + ' AS [' + name + ']' from USER_META WHERE UID = 5 for xml path('')`